# "No key" flashes on dash board with key inside car

Tags: honda, keyless-entry, city

My Honda City model 2016 has a push button keyless starter and while the engine is running, it flashes "no Key" on the dashboard when the passenger side door is open.  Why?

Comment: could be that it's a safety feature. Does this happen with all doors or just the passenger door?